# navigation on jquery-tools scrollable always disable

Tags: jquery, clone, jquery-tools, addclass

I can't get the scrollable navigation to work, when I'm cloning the DIVS 
it should fire. I want the scroll to start when the divs are cloned.

any idea?

http://jsfiddle.net/2mby5/13/

or

```
var cloneCount = 0;
$("#add-address").click(function() {

     $("#to-add-address").clone()
        .attr("id", "to-add-address_Clone" + cloneCount)
        .insertAfter("#to-add-address").addClass('cloned');  //add a new class cloned to the cloned outerDivs
    $(".clone", "#to-add-address_Clone" + cloneCount)
        .attr("id", "clone_Clone" + cloneCount);
    cloneCount++;
     $('#scroll-addresses').scrollable();
});



$(document).on("click", '.options li a',function () {
            $(this).closest(".options").find('li a').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');

        });
$(document).on("click", 'li.delete',function () {
            $(this).closest(".outerDiv").filter('.cloned').remove(); // and delete only the cloned ones
    if ($(this).is(".outerDiv:last")){
            return false;
    }   
});

 ​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"You must have a root element for the scrollable and inside that another wrapper element for the items."

http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/index.html

Comment: can't really find the difference, looks fine to me.

Comment: thanks for your message but I can't really make this work, could you check it for me please?

Comment: Try laying out your code just like the example, see if it works, then tweak as needed.

Comment: could you cke it out? I need another eye as looks all fine to me:-(

Comment: I did check it out, and you're not following the format prescribed in the directions (like putting each "group" of items into its own div.)

Comment: the div div's in my case are the li's

Comment: I think is something to do with Firing the scrollable. the css are fine

Comment: I set a breakpoint and it fires just fine, and enters the external scrollable js. If the code is looking for divs, using lis won't cut it.